# Hide UIButton for 3 seconds and then reveal after 3 seconds are up

Tags: objective-c, ipad, ios7, uibutton

I have a loading screen in my app that just shows 5 pictures that have different opacities disappearing in front of each other for 3 seconds. I have buttons that show a log in screen. I am trying to hide the log in and sign up buttons for 3 seconds and then after that time is up show them right at the same time the loading screen sequence completes. Can anyone help me?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please provide some code that you already have?

Answer (score 3):

```
button.hidden = YES;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    button.hidden = NO;
});
```

What this says is to hide the button then schedule a block to run after 3 billion nanoseconds on the main thread that unhides the button.

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out

Answer (score 0):

Completing rob5408 answer. If you want some animation, you can do something like this

```
button.alpha = 0.0f;
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(3 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
     [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5f animations:^{
        button.alpha = 1.0f;
    }];
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Figured it out